# what email should i use to create a sender?

Tags: twilio, sendgrid, twilio-api

before sending the first email i need to fill up this form.
but as you can see it gives me a warning to not use gmail as my account.
I went to the link and read why but they didn't give any alternative what should I do.

i just need to send mail for a personal project and I also don't own any company and I don't live in the US
[image]
I am from the middle east

so I don't know what to insert is here
[image]

any help please ?

Comment: Most hosting companies you can get a domain and at least one month of e-mail for less than 20 bucks.

Comment: but if i have email why i need send grid ?

Comment: i dont have moeny i am a student , don't have a job , so I don't want to spend money

Comment: i ended up using nodemailer and render and I found a provider like you said that for 1 $ I get 10,000 emails and a domain its called ionos